# How to create a draggable vertival line in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, indicator

I'm trying to create a indicator with a vertical line that is "draggable", I found an indicator that already do what I'm trying to do, the name is "Just a vertical line" (short title is "JaVL").

Any ideas ?

[Screenshot of the indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/890BU.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `confirm` parameter:

```
a = input.time(timestamp("Jan 2 2023"), confirm = true)
b = input.time(timestamp("Jan 5 2023"), confirm = true)
```

The time of the bar you'll choose will be the value of the variable. If you want to change the value late, you can press on the script name and the lines will reappear.